# angularjs, ngResource in a factory and network calls

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

Trying to get my head around this. I have a simple factory using ngResouce, like this:

```
   .factory('FooResource', function($resource) {

    var foo = $resource('/api/foo').get();

    return foo;

   })
```

And in my app, in multiple places, in multiple controllers over time, I use the value of 'FooResource.bar' (where 'bar' is returned in the data from the get() call).

Is it true that the network call to '/api/foo' will only happen on the first reference for the life of my SPA? Does that first reference need to 'FooResource.bar' be handled like a promise?

From what I see in my playing around with code, it seems like the first question is 'yes' and the second is 'no', but don't know if that's really true in general, or just happening because its a small test app on my dev box.

Edit: I guess part of what I want validation on is my thinking that since this is in a factory, which is a singelton, the $resource call will only ever be made once. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends, and yes. You will always need to handle it as a promise, and you can enable/disable the http cache. If you have the cache set to true, then the request will send off once and be cached until the cache is cleared.

You can find more about the $resource caching in the $resource documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: I added an edit wondering if the $resource call will only be made once because this in a factory/singleton.